# Returning to Native App from Gmail (or other native app) WebView Browser in Android

Tags: android, webview, deep-linking, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

User Flow

- user opens app, taps "forgot password"
- "forgot password" email is sent
- user opens forgot password email, website opens in gmail browser
- password is reset, website displays "return to app"
- return to app button is a deep link / app link
- gmail browser does not allow user to open the deep link and navigates, resulting in a 404

This seems to be affecting all webviews. The links are "Universal/App" links, so they start with "https://"

For the record this is working in iOS.

Couldn't find any other posts about this specifically, apologies if duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a bit of research the immediate workaround is to use an intent because app links are simply broke inside webviews you don't control.

```
<a href="intent://applink.com/path/of/link#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.acme.packagename;end">Link</a>
```